# How to change the collation for routines over the selected Database?

Tags: mysql

the collation of every routine in my DB should be utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.
but for some reason, I'm seeing utf8mb4_general_ci
instead of altering every routine to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
is there any way to update all the routine's collation to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci?
please help me out

```
| character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
| utf8mb4              | utf8mb4_general_ci   | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | exisiting
| utf8mb4              | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci   | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | expected to be
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.